# How to write this formula out as an algebraic equation

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

I've been developing some basic hash algorithms for cryptanalylis purposes, and would like to know how to represent it as an algebraic equation. The algorithm follows thus:

Basic python code

```
p = [97, 111, 105, 122, 108, 107]
s = [107, 101, 121, 107, 101, 121]
c = []

for i in range(len(p)):

    alpha = p[i + 1:] + p[:i]  # With p as 97 alpha = [111, ..., 107], with p as 111, [105, ..., 97]

    tmp = p[i]  # First run 97, 2nd run 111 etc.

    for x in alhpa:  # 1st run 111, then 105 etc.

        tmp = tmp ^ x ^ s[x] if s[x] exists else s[x%len(s)]  # If s[x] exists XOR against that or s[x mod len(s)] to make s[x] exist
    c.append(tmp)  # Adds tmp to the output.
```

Sample output of above algorithm:

```
With p as [97, 111, 105, 122, 108, 107]
With s as [107, 101, 121, 107, 101, 121]
New cycle 1
[97, 'xor', 111, 'xor', 107] -> 101
[101, 'xor', 105, 'xor', 107] -> 103
[103, 'xor', 122, 'xor', 121] -> 100
[100, 'xor', 108, 'xor', 107] -> 99
[99, 'xor', 107, 'xor', 121] -> 113
New cycle 2
[111, 'xor', 105, 'xor', 107] -> 109
[109, 'xor', 122, 'xor', 121] -> 110
[110, 'xor', 108, 'xor', 107] -> 105
[105, 'xor', 107, 'xor', 121] -> 123
[123, 'xor', 97, 'xor', 101] -> 127
New cycle 3
[105, 'xor', 122, 'xor', 121] -> 106
[106, 'xor', 108, 'xor', 107] -> 109
[109, 'xor', 107, 'xor', 121] -> 127
[127, 'xor', 97, 'xor', 101] -> 123
[123, 'xor', 111, 'xor', 107] -> 127
New cycle 4
[122, 'xor', 108, 'xor', 107] -> 125
[125, 'xor', 107, 'xor', 121] -> 111
[111, 'xor', 97, 'xor', 101] -> 107
[107, 'xor', 111, 'xor', 107] -> 111
[111, 'xor', 105, 'xor', 107] -> 109
New cycle 5
[108, 'xor', 107, 'xor', 121] -> 126
[126, 'xor', 97, 'xor', 101] -> 122
[122, 'xor', 111, 'xor', 107] -> 126
[126, 'xor', 105, 'xor', 107] -> 124
[124, 'xor', 122, 'xor', 121] -> 127
New cycle 6
[107, 'xor', 97, 'xor', 101] -> 111
[111, 'xor', 111, 'xor', 107] -> 107
[107, 'xor', 105, 'xor', 107] -> 105
[105, 'xor', 122, 'xor', 121] -> 106
[106, 'xor', 108, 'xor', 107] -> 109
[113, 127, 127, 109, 127, 109]  # ASCII encoded output - value of c
['q', '\x7f', '\x7f', 'm', '\x7f', 'm']  # ASCII decoded output - value of c
```

How would I write this as a single formula, that would still be valid no matter what the length of $p$ is?

Comment: binary XOR is commutative and associative. All $C_k$ has the same value, you can represent it as $C = \bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^n p_k$.
In fact, one can view an ascii character as a vector in a $7$-dim vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (It takes 7 bits to encode an ASCII character).  XOR between two ascii characters is the vector addition between corresponding vectors.

Comment: @achillehui I must apologize that that went over my head... Could you please repeat in layman's terms, or more basic math? I've never been quite that good.

Comment: Binary XOR behaves like ordinary addition, you can carry out the XOR in any order and any grouping you like and get back same result. Similar to the use of $\sum$ as a short hand for a sum,
$$\underbrace{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}_{\text{in any order or grouping}} =\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \stackrel{def}{=} (((a_1 + a_2) + a_3) \cdots + a_n)$$
One can use $\bigoplus$ as a shorthand for multiple binary XOR
$$\underbrace{a_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_n}_{\text{in any order or grouping}} = \bigoplus_{k=1}^n a_k \stackrel{def}{=} (((a_1 \oplus a_2) \oplus a_3) \cdots \oplus a_n)$$

Comment: Oh I see your point... I'll post a modification to fix that error. Can you read python code? It'll make it easier if I can post the code

Comment: Note that your $C_i$ are all the same as $\oplus$ is commutive and associative.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I realised after achille hue pointed it out. I'm going to post a slight change in my algorithm in a few minutes

Comment: @HennoBrandsma edited

Comment: @achillehui edited the algo

Comment: Given any 1-dim array $A$, let $|A|$ be its length and extend indexing of its entries by periodicity. i.e $A[i] \stackrel{def}{=} A[{\rm mod}(i, |A|)]$ for $0 < i$ or $i \ge |A|$. Given array $p$, what you are doing is generating $|p|$ vectors $c_0, c_1, \ldots c_{|p|-1}$ of length $|p|-1$ with entries of the form
$$c_i[j] = p[i] \oplus \bigoplus_{k=1}^{j+1} (p[i+k] \oplus s[p[i+k]])\quad\text{ for }\quad 0 < j < |p|-1$$
Is this the sort of "equation" you are looking for???